# Confusion over usage of に

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-に, sentence

I am not 100% sure what role に is playing in this sentence.

> 「そんなこと、記憶にありません」

I understand the sentences meaning (something along the lines of "I do not remember that") but I think I'm missing something as to why に is being used here.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This に is a location-of-existence marker used with ある, いる, ない, etc. You probably know this already, but if you need a refresher, see: https://www.learn-japanese-adventure.com/arimasu-imasu-existence.html

記憶 is treated as a location, and そんなこと is the subject (は is omitted after そんなこと). Thus the literal translation is "There is no such thing in my memory" or "Such a thing does not exist in my memory".